# Swift. Как отправить команду(строку) на сервер?

Tags: qt, swift, сервер, client

У меня есть локальный сервер:

```
ip:192.168.1.30
port: 8888 
request:D0074\r\n
```

Я уже облазил весь интернет и никак не могу объединить все что там написанно, где то код без ввода команды где то пишет ошибку. Помогите пожалуйста как я могу послать данную команду `D0074\r\n` на мой сервер? Помогите пожалуйста

Вот как реализовал на с++:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а в чем именно трудность? какие варианты пробовали? например https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364914/http-request-in-swift-with-post-method

Comment: для начала можно проверить `192.168.1.30:8888` в браузере

Comment: @schmidt9 в браузере все нормально, я не понимаю как это через код делать, там в коде слишком много написано и я не понимаю куда вводит порт и куда саму команду((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Опираясь на [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26365148/3004003), в вашем случае будет что-то вроде

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://192.168.1.30:8888/your_script.php")!)
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpMethod = "POST"

let parameters: [String : Any] = [
    "data" : "D0074\n\r"
]
```

**Дополнение**

Судя по реализации на С++, нужен tcp socket, вышеуказанный вариант не подойдет, для реализации на свифт для удобства можно использовать библиотеку [SwiftSocket](https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket)

```
send(command: "D0074\r\n", address: "192.168.1.30", port: 8888)
```

```
func send(command: String, address: String, port: Int32) {

    let client = TCPClient(address: address, port: port)
    switch client.connect(timeout: 1) {
      case .success:
        switch client.send(string: command ) {
          case .success:
            guard let data = client.read(1024*10) else { return }

            if let response = String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf8) {
              print(response)
            }
          case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
      case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109236/discussion-on-answer-by-schmidt9-swift-----).